# I want to know how many types of arguments in java

Tags: java, methods

I am a beginner in java. Sometimes I saw a method would return a int type, sometimes a string type, I want to how many arguments type in java. 
for example:
I create a method:

```
public int dog(int i, String j , double k);
```

Could all the primitive types and reference types be used in the bracket  ?

Comment: I recommend you the book *Thinking in Java*.

Comment: int, byte, short, char.....

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: Infinite.

There is no limit. Depending on what classes you write and what you want to do with the language, your functions can take any number of argument types and return any valid class type you write. Since you can write these classes until you run out of ideas, there is no limit.

For example: I can write a `Dog` class and do this:

```
public Dog getDog() {
    return new Dog();
}
```

Dog isn't a primitive type. But it's still valid. I can make as many of these valid classes as I like.

Answer (score 0):

A method can return any `primitive` or any `Object`. All classes in Java by default `extends` from `Object`. So there is no concrete answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Practically everything in java is an object and every object has a type. You can create new objects with any kind of abstract type that comes in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

User Defined Types and Primitive Types can passed as parameter for method. Similarly the return could be any type or even void.